# PyQt5 add QScrollArea to a Frame or a Widget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to hide a QScrollArea which displays pages of PDF files. I know how to hide widgets and frames, and so I want to add the QScrollArea to either one of them so that it can be hidden. I tried setStyleSheet ('height:0px;'), which doesn't work.

This is the sample Code taken from https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/qscrollarea/#adding%20a%20qscrollarea%20from%20code. Specific to this code how do I add self.scroll to a frame or a widget?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic, QtMultimediaWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()             # Scroll Area which contains the widgets, set as the centralWidget
        self.widget = QWidget()                 # Widget that contains the collection of Vertical Box
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()               # The Vertical Box that contains the Horizontal Boxes of  labels and buttons

        self.pageLabel0 = QLabel()
        self.pageLabel0.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.pageLabel0PageImage = QPixmap('pdfs/page_0.png').scaledToWidth(self.width(), Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.pageLabel0.setPixmap(self.pageLabel0PageImage)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.pageLabel0)

        self.pageLabel1 = QLabel()
        self.pageLabel1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.pageLabel1PageImage = QPixmap('pdfs/page_1.png').scaledToWidth(self.width(), Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.pageLabel1.setPixmap(self.pageLabel1PageImage)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.pageLabel1)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

        #Scroll Area Properties
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Area Demonstration')
        self.show()

        return

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: 1) you are adding the widgets to the scrollarea, while in your explanation it seems the other way around, can you be more clear? 2) Qt stylesheets are mostly for *visual customization of the underlying Qt style*, and they shall not be used just like as they were normal "web css"; if you want to hide a widget, use [`hide()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide) or [`setVisible(False)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#visible-prop). 3) the question "how do I add self.scroll to a frame or a widget?" isn't clear, and only a single question can be asked in each post anyway.

Comment: Appreciate the downvotes to the question, really. No sarcasm. I didn't try enough ways, I'm new to PyQt AND python. I used `setLayout()` function to add a layout containing the `QScrollArea()` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `self.scroll.hide()` to your code.